# PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null) returns zero services

Tags: java, printing, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am creating a J2EE web project using jsf and prime faces. I want to print a jasper report by using print report button. I am using this code to do it and when I run this code it gives zero services as output.

```
PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);

        System.out.println("****************Services");
        for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("services==="+services[i].getName());
        }
```

I have run this on net beans standalone application and it lists available services. But in eclipse, it does not return anything. When in debug mode when I get my cursor on top of "service" object, this displays as tooltip

"org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array."

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: I would presume that there is a SecurityManager that denies you access to the local machine resources (Applets have very limited permissions). Since the right hand expression (lookupPrintServices) executes first (and probably throws SecurityException), the left hand expression is not evaluated. Put a catch block around it and see what it throws.

Comment: @Durandal Thanks for quick reply. How can i give security permissions for applet to access local machine resources. I have go to java control panel and change security level to medium. is that the way to give permission for applets.

Comment: Unfortunately I have practically no experience with the combo Applet/Web/Java. I believe you have to sign the code. Check this article http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html and possibly this one http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/java-applet/662-how-sign-java-applet.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will tryout this and let u know the results.